# fast convert double to uint64_t in thread safe way

Tags: c, parallel-processing, bit-manipulation

I have the below function that I call in a parallel loop. I have declared the `union` inside the below function for thread safety. The issue is that doing so slow things a lot. My question is whether there is a way to turn the `double` into an `uin64_t` (the same way as `union` does) but in a faster way? Thank you.

```
uint64_t flip(double d) {
  union {double d; uint64_t u64;} u;
  u.d = d;
  return u.u64 ^ (-(u.u64 >> 63) | 0x8000000000000000ULL);
}
```

I am using gcc to compile the code.

Comment: if you want to (really) *convert* why are you not doing `uint64_t flip(double d) { return d; }` ?

Comment: *The issue is that doing so slow things a lot.* Compared to what? There is no 'operation' as such inside the union when you access the member other than the one you wrote. It's just a memory access.

Comment: First, document your code. The operation `u.u64 ^ (-(u.u64 >> 63) | 0x8000000000000000ULL)` is cryptic. Experienced programmers may recognize it as flipping the encodings of negative floating-point data and know why this is done (because of the ordering relative to two’s complement integers), but you should state it in your second.

Comment: Second, state what compiler you are using and what switches/options you are using and show the generated assembly code. The code that results from reinterpreting a union as another member should be straightforward, such as a move from a floating-point register to an integer register (or through memory if the processor architecture requires), and the speed of this might be limited by hardware and not due to either how it is expressed in C or how much the compiler optimizes. Examining the generated assembly is important for determining this.

Comment: Also, do not call this a conversion. A conversion is a function that takes an argument of one type and returns a value of (usually) a different type that represents the *same* value as nearly as possible. For example, when 3.2 kilometers is converted to 2 miles, the distance is the same. Or when floating-point −3 is converted to integer −3, the value is the same. What you are doing is getting the encoding of a floating-point number, not converting it.

Comment: I suspect that the majority of the time is spent on the `call` and `return` instructions. You might see if your compiler can inline this function.

Comment: I have tried to inline the function but it does not change anything.

Comment: As Adrian said, "compared to what"?  You make it sound like you had some other version that was faster, but not thread-safe.  I'm having trouble imagining what a non-thread-safe version of this function would even look like, let alone how it could be faster.  Can you show what you had before?

Comment: I don't have anything thread safe faster than this. If I was not using parallelism, I would have not created the function in the first place and the union would be declared outside where the above function is used. This is actually faster than using the above function.

Comment: So it sounds to me like maybe it's actually the *parallelism* that is slowing your program down.  This is not uncommon when you first parallelize a task, due to cache contention, etc.  Maybe it would help to give some more context, and show two versions of a complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try re-doing this as a macro to eliminate the `call` and `return` overhead for the function:

```
#define DOUBLE_TO_UINT64(d) ((*(uint64_t *)(&(d))) ^ (-( (*(uint64_t *)(&(d))) >> 63) | 0x8000000000000000ULL))
```

Comment: The output of the above MACRO is different than the flip function.

Comment: I don't know what you're passing as an argument but [the function and macro produce identical results at OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/SaDgax5sq).

Comment: Sorry my mistake. You are right. Your MACRO does return the same. I will wait a bit before accepting your answer, just to see if other users have different or better solutions. Plus your answer does speed things a bit .Thank you.

Comment: This macro is a strict-aliasing violation.  You can't safely treat a `double` as a `uint64_t`, especially when optimizing at a high level.  I also doubt that it's any faster than the `union` method used in the original question.